# Gramática: reflexivo

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

Dice que

> El reflexivo tiene un valor factitivo: No es el que hace directamente la acción, sino quien la ordena hacer.
>   · Nos hicimos una casa en el pueblo.
>   · Ayer me corté el pelo.

I do not understand the above. What is "valor factitivo"? From my understanding, reflexive means "part of" or "property of" someone. Are these the same cases?

And how about "Me da una manzana, por favor." Is "*me*" a "valor factitivo" since it is an order?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1. What is the function of "factitivo"? To emphasize the subject?
2. If I write "ayer me cortó el pelo" and "nos hicieron una casa en el pueblo¨, do they have the same meaning of the above sentences?
3. The use of "valor factitivo" is only used during the condition of making an order?
4. Are all the verbs of "valor factitivo" being the first person such as "corté", "hicimos"?

Comment: You should probably cite the source of that quote.

Comment: I could not do it because it is from a conversation.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought it was copied from a book/website.

Answer (score 1):

From RAE:

> ~ factitivo. 1. m. Gram. verbo, o perífrasis verbal, cuyo sujeto no ejecuta por sí mismo la acción, sino que la hace ejecutar por otro.

According to this, "factitivo" verbs are, for instance, "hacerse", "cortarse", "construirse", "prepararse", etc. In these verbs, the subject is not actually performing the action but other person.

In this case, the "se" pronoun (normally used as reflexive prononun) is used along with the verb to turn it into a "factitivo" verb.

Using your examples:

> Nos hicimos una casa en el pueblo

It means that we had our house built in the village (by other people)

> Ayer me corté el pelo

It means that I had my hair cut (by the hairdresser).

With regard to the example

> Me da una manzana, por favor

In this case, the "me" pronoun is play the role of indirect object

**Updated:**

> What is the function of "factitivo"? To emphasize the subject?

To emphasize that someone performed the action

> If I write "ayer me cortó el pelo" and "nos hicieron una casa en el pueblo¨, do they have the same meaning of the above sentences?

In "Ayer me corté el pelo" the verb is the first person singular whereas in "Ayer me cortó el pelo" the verb is the third person singular. Both means the same alghouh the first one is a "factitivo" verb and the second one is a normal verb and "me" is the dative.

> The use of "valor factitivo" is only used during the condition of making an order?

An order, a petition, a favour, etc...

> Are all the verbs of "valor factitivo" being the first person such as "corté", "hicimos"?

No, you can say "Él se cortó el pelo", meaning that he had his hair cut.

Comment: How do we distinguish whether it is a "valor factitivo"?

Comment: @Cadenza I think that the best way is to study some of them. When you really understand how it works, you will be able to identify the rest on your own